# How to set firebase analytics events with ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm trying to get my analytics events with firebase but all I get is only session_start event. I'm using the firebase [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics/) for ionic.

This is my code:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private nav: NavController,
            private firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics) {
    this.firebaseAnalytics.setEnabled(true);
    this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent('home_page_viewed', {page: "dashboard"})
        .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
        .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    }
```

So, I expect to see in firebase console an event that called 'home_page_viewed' but I don't see such event. All I see is only session_start event.

Anyone knows what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have lazy-loading enabled in your application and a page view does not always create a new page object. So the construct method is NOT called for every page view.

Further the `constructor` method of the page class is not the correct place to log a page-view.

You should move the `logEvent` call to one of Ionic's [lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events).

```
public ionViewDidEnter()
{
  this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent('home_page_viewed', {page: 'dashboard'})
    .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
    .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
}
```